# find function in mongodb gives a data and need to access one key and value from it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using nodemailer to send mail to send the mail i need to find the user from his unique id so i did that and it returned me the user.. when i do console.log(data) it prints all the details of user in terminal but I need to access the email from it but when i do data.email it shows undefined.. have a look at my code and pls help if you can

```
app.post('/person-found-form',upload,  function(req, res) {
Post_found.create({
    unique_name : req.body.unique_name,
    yname : req.body.yname,
    email : req.body.email,
    phone : req.body.phone,
    address : req.body.address,
    nps : req.body.nps,
    details : req.body.details,
    image : req.file.filename,
},
function(err, post) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(post);
    Post.find({unique : post.unique_name},function(err, data) {
        console.log(data.email);
    })
```

})
});

Answer (score 0):

The Mongoose function `Model.find` returns an array of documents.  If you are certain there will be only one, or you only want the first one, use `Model.findOne` which returns a single object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I already solved it but what I did was finding it through id so it gives specific result.... And sir thanks for the reply...